# Why would this wire be shielded?

Tags: sensor, automotive, shielding

I'm trying to work out how I might emulate this assembly to replace the seat weight sensors below. I'd guess the sensors are just strain gauges, so a variable resistance or maybe capacitance. Unfortunately the control module is a black box. I can't see why the red/blu wire would be shielded. Any ideas what signal it might be carrying?

[image: extract from schematic]

Comment: Where do the RED/BLU and BLK/WHT conductors go (i.e. what module)?

Comment: You are looking at the wiring diagram. You should also look at the connector pinout diagram. They have more information about the connections, it would give you a hint.

Answer (score 6):

First note that you are messing with systems directly related to the control of your vehicle's airbags - a safety critical system that can really hurt you or kill you:

1. If you need it to work and it doesn't, and
2. If you expect it to not work and it does

Work on this system at your own risk.

The Weight Sensor Control Module provides amplification and filtering for individual seat sensors.  It interfaces to the airbag control module using a proprietary protocol that you will need to reverse engineer with a scope and/or protocol analyzer  (sorry - automotive electronics is tough if you don't have support from an OEM (Original Equipment Manufacturer) or supplier.

A typical arrangement [looks like this](http://www.rx8club.com/attachments/rx-8-racing-25/179966d1325026146-my-new-seats-06-seatweightsensor-pdf) 
(your sub-circuit in green box -- note that in for the vehicle shown, the line is not shielded).

[image]

Comment: +1 Nice work (and interesting!) Looks like this one uses unshielded differential-pair, while the OP's uses a shielded wire.

Comment: Yes, very nice thank you. I understand the safety implications, and indeed am improving safety by emulating a working sensor, where there was a u/s one before. The cost of replacing the sensor is so great that it won't be done, leaving the whole system inoperative.   That out of the way, I believe the strain gauges are the faulty component, not the control module, and so I believe I should be able to replace them with carefully chosen resistors. If I have to emulate the module, it's probably too much for me right now, since I don't have a scope!

Comment: (however I do have a multimeter on its way that can measure PWM frequency and duty cycle, so if that's the protocol I might be in luck)

Answer (score 2):

With the limited information you've given, I can only guess that it's a low level analog signal that needs to be isolated from potential interference. Perhaps it's being routed near a noise source, or perhaps it's a longer run that has more potential for pickup.

Answer (score 2):

@BobT's nailed it.

Automobiles are a horribly noisy electrical environment coupled with high reliability requirements and cost sensitivity. That line has to run some distance back to the main body/cabin control module (typically near the passenger foot well).

Long-run plus sensitive signal = shielding required for reliability.

Without more detail it will be difficult to say precisely why. Either it is to protect the signal from interference (signal is the *victim*) or it is to prevent the signal from generating interference to nearby wiring (signal is the *agressor*).